# Using javascript to randomly open .html files on a single folder?

Tags: javascript, html

I need the bare minimum of code I can use to:

1. open new .html webpages by clicking on a button that
2. pops up a new window and when clicked "OK"
3. a new .html webpage is opened **randomly**
4. all dynamically happening inside one folder.

I'm just beginning to walk on my feet, so please bear with my rookie status. Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "single folder"?

Comment: Well, I guess I'm trying to say is they're all in one directory, but that part isn't that important, I mainly wanna get something where randomly opens different .html files through javascirpts' "popquiz" style window-opening, and when clicked OK, it opens a new .html file.

I would love it if the code is as short as possible.

Comment: Do you have access to the folder settings on the server? To make this automatic, you'll need a setting on the server that allows you to read directory contents. If you're happy to specify all the HTML files, then Nerdman's answer is best.

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself yet?  What did you try, how did it work out?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot read folder contents with javascript directly but you can store possible url's to an variable as an array. Window.open will open the window. For example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var urls = [url1, url2, ...]; 
$("#my_button").click(window.open(urls[Math.floor((Math.random()*urls.length))]))
</script>
```

[jQuery](http://jquery.com/) is needed for the example to work.

You can add urls also programmatically. To print all htmls files with ruby you could do something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var urls = <%= raw Dir.glob("*html") %>
....
</script>
```

Comment: Hey thanks! Where do I place my actual urls in the following code you provided?

Comment: You need to edit your html file for that, for example var urls = ["http://stackoverflow.com", "http://google.com"]. I suggest you to learn more javascript, its interesting and fun, here you go: http://www.w3schools.com/js/.